# flutter : use index in position , stack parent

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, flutter-listview, flutter-positioned

i have to use index in position , but when I use listView.builder for I , I got this error :

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Positioned(left: 157.2) wants to apply ParentData
> of type StackParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to
> accept ParentData of incompatible type FlexParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Positioned widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Positioned widgets are placed directly
> inside Stack widgets. The offending Positioned is currently placed
> inside a Row widget.

and app crashed.

i use `stack` -> `listview.bulder`(for index) -> `position`

but correct is `stack` -> `position`

I have to use index in position.
so can anyone help me how can I do that ?

for example myList are :

```
myList = [{"data" : 100.0},{"data" : 200.0 },{"data" : 300.0 }, {"data" :400.0 },{"data" : 500.0} ]
```

here is my code :

```
Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                          left: (myList[index]["data"]),
                          child: Directionality(
                            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                            child: MySimpleIcons(
                              iconName: MyIcons.bookProfile,
                              iconColor: theme.darkGrey,
                              iconSize: 24,
                            ),
                          ),
                 // another widgets
                 ) ],
```

Comment: Where is this `ListView` added in your code? in the stack or outside?

Comment: out , i need it for left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .map & spread operator to fulfill this case. You can try the following code:

```
Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
      children: [
        ...myList.map((position) => Positioned(
                  left: position,
                  child: Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    child: MySimpleIcons(
                      iconName: MyIcons.bookProfile,
                      iconColor: theme.darkGrey,
                      iconSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            // another widgets
            )
      ],
    );
```